# Combine Arrays (Overlay with offset)

Tags: c#, arrays

Given a source array of floating point numbers between -1 and 1, I want to manipulate the array to combine with itself at given offsets. I think the easiest way to describe this in more detail is by example:

```
sourceArray: [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, -0.5, -1.0]
offsets: [0,1,2]
```

This would result in 3 arrays to be combined. The offsets actually shift the array, keeping the length.

```
o0: [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, -0.5, -1.0]
o1: [-1.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, -0.5]
o2: [-0.5, -1.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
```

After combining the arrays (sum per position), the result would be:

```
[-1.4, -0.7, 0.6, 0.0, -1,2]
```

I have implemented a loop which generates correct results, but it is way too slow because my source arrays are much bigger and I have to do the calculation numerous times with different offsets.

Is there a faster way to achieve this using C#?

Comment: It would be helpful to know your implementation language.

Comment: It would also be helpful to see your implementation.

Comment: It would also help if you said what language you're using.

Comment: You should be able to do what you want using the modulus operator. `(i + offset) % length` will get you the index in that offset array.

Comment: `o3` is only shifted 2 places, not 3.

Comment: "Too slow" doesn't tell us anything that we can use to help you.  How big are the arrays?  How slow is it?  Have you used a profiler to determine where the hot spot is?  Where was it? How fast is "fast enough"?  When will you know when to stop optimizing?

Comment: Do you actually need to materialize the sum array all at once? Why not materialize each element "on demand" when asked for it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `mod` is going to be the slowest operation in the standard implementation of this problem. Fortunately, if the offsets are sorted then we can remove the need for `mod` by breaking iterations through `arr` into phases, where in each phase we can be sure that the offset array index stays within bounds.

Hopefully you don't mind me illustrating in Java? I believe it should convert almost 1-1 with C#:

```
static double[] sumOffsetsNoMod(double[] arr, int[] off)
{
  double[] sum = new double[arr.length];
  for(int i=0, p=off.length-1 ; i<arr.length; p--)
  {
    int top = arr.length-off[p];
    for(; i<top; i++)
      for(int j=0; j<off.length; j++)
        sum[i+off[j]] += arr[i];
    off[p] -= arr.length;
  }

  // restore off
  for(int i=0; i<off.length; i++) off[i] += arr.length;

  return sum;
}
```

Note that we have to modify the value of the offsets to turn them from right shifts into left shifts as we move through the phases. For correctness we restore the offsets to their original values at the end.

But is all this extra effort worth it I hear you say? Well, in a completely non-scientific timing test against a reference implementation that uses `mod` the non-mod version is quite a bit faster:

```
Mod   : 1485ms
NoMod : 863ms
```

For reference:

```
static double[] sumOffsetsMod(double[] arr, int[] off)
{
  double[] sum = new double[arr.length];
  for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<off.length; j++)
      sum[(i+off[j])%arr.length] += arr[i];
  return sum;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  double[] arr = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, -0.5, -1.0};
  int[] off = {0,1,4};

  int n=10000000;
  long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    double[] sum = sumOffsetsMod(arr, off);
  }
  System.out.printf("Mod   : %dms\n", (System.currentTimeMillis()-t));
  t = System.currentTimeMillis();
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    double[] sum = sumOffsetsNoMod(arr, off);
  }
  System.out.printf("NoMod : %dms\n", (System.currentTimeMillis()-t));
}
```

Comment: Did the test in C# in debug mode. withMod 516ms, withoutMod 96ms

Comment: Thanks @Aldert that's quite a difference.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the pseudo-code:

```
for i from 0 to length(sourceArray)-1
    total = 0
    for j from 0 to length(offsets)-1
        total = total + sourceArray[(i + offsets[j]) % length(sourceArray)]
    result[i] = total
```

This is `O(n*m)` where `n` is `length(sourceArray)` and `m` is `length(offsets)`

If you have plenty of memory, you can avoid doing all the modulus operations by materializing all the offset arrays:

```
arrays = []
for offset in offsets:
    arrays.push(sourceArray[0:offset] + sourceArray[-offset:])
```

Then you can loop through arrays:

```
result = arrays[0]
for array in arrays[1:]:
    for i from 0 to length(array)-1:
        result[i] += array[i]
```

Comment: Thats about what my implementation looks like. Unfortunately it is really slow with large arrays and many offsets...

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do it that won't be `O(n*m)`. That's how many additions you have to do to produce the results you want. I can't think of any shortcuts that are possible.

Comment: I've added another method that doesn't use modulus, by creating all the offset arrays initially. It's still O(n*m), but the coefficient may be lower because less work is done each step